# Keyboard is not responsive on xorg-server-1.13.1

Tags: xorg, gentoo

When I've upgraded to xorg-server-1.13.1 keyboard stopped functioning.
I then downgrade to xorg-server-1.12.4 and xorg-drivers-1.12 and it works now.

My USE flags for both xorg-server and xorg-drivers below:

```
$ equery u xorg-server
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for x11-base/xorg-server-1.12.4:
 U I
 - - dmx         : Build the Distributed Multiheaded X server
 - - doc         : Adds extra documentation (API, Javadoc, etc). It is recommended to enable per package instead of globally
 - - ipv6        : Adds support for IP version 6
 - - kdrive      : Build the kdrive X servers
 - - minimal     : Install a very minimal build (disables, for example, plugins, fonts, most drivers, non-critical features)
 + + nptl        : Enable support for Native POSIX Threads Library, the new threading module (requires linux-2.6 or better usually)
 - - static-libs : Build static libraries
 - - tslib       : Build with tslib support for touchscreen devices
 + + udev        : Enable sys-fs/udev integration (device discovery, power and storage device support, etc)
 + + xnest       : Build the Xnest server
 + + xorg        : Build the Xorg X server (HIGHLY RECOMMENDED)
 - - xvfb        : Build the Xvfb server
 archer@capitan ~ $ equery u xorg-drivers
 [ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
 [        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
 [ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for x11-base/xorg-drivers-1.12:
 U I
 - - input_devices_acecad      : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for acecad input devices
 - - input_devices_aiptek      : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for aiptek input devices
 - - input_devices_elographics : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for elographics input devices
 + + input_devices_evdev       : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for evdev input devices
 - - input_devices_fpit        : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for fpit input devices
 - - input_devices_hyperpen    : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for hyperpen input devices
 - - input_devices_joystick    : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for joystick input devices
 + + input_devices_keyboard    : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for keyboard input devices
 + + input_devices_mouse       : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for mouse input devices
 - - input_devices_mutouch     : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for mutouch input devices
 - - input_devices_penmount    : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for penmount input devices
 - - input_devices_synaptics   : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for synaptics input devices
 - - input_devices_tslib       : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for tslib input devices
 - - input_devices_vmmouse     : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for vmmouse input devices
 - - input_devices_void        : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for void/dummy input devices
 - - input_devices_wacom       : INPUT_DEVICES setting to build driver for wacom input devices
 - - video_cards_apm           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for apm video cards
 - - video_cards_ark           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for ark video cards
 - - video_cards_ast           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for ASpeedTech video cards
 - - video_cards_cirrus        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for cirrus video cards
 - - video_cards_dummy         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for dummy video cards
 - - video_cards_epson         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for epson video cards
 - - video_cards_fbdev         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for fbdev video cards
 - - video_cards_fglrx         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for fglrx video cards
 - - video_cards_glint         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for glint video cards
 - - video_cards_i128          : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for Number 9 I128 video cards
 - - video_cards_intel         : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for Intel video cards
 - - video_cards_mach64        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for mach64 video cards
 - - video_cards_mga           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for mga video cards
 - - video_cards_modesetting   : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for unaccelerated modesetting
 - - video_cards_neomagic      : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for neomagic video cards
 - - video_cards_nouveau       : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build reverse-engineered driver for nvidia cards
 - - video_cards_nv            : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for nv video cards
 + + video_cards_nvidia        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for nvidia video cards
 - - video_cards_qxl           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for qxl (QEMU virtual GPU)
 - - video_cards_r128          : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for ATI r128 video cards
 - - video_cards_radeon        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for ATI radeon video cards
 - - video_cards_s3            : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for s3 video cards
 - - video_cards_s3virge       : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for s3virge video cards
 - - video_cards_savage        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for savage video cards
 - - video_cards_siliconmotion : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for siliconmotion video cards
 - - video_cards_sis           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for SiS video cards
 - - video_cards_tdfx          : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for tdfx video cards
 - - video_cards_tga           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for tga video cards
 - - video_cards_trident       : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for trident video cards
 - - video_cards_v4l           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for v4l video cards
 - - video_cards_vesa          : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for vesa video cards
 - - video_cards_via           : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for via video cards
 - - video_cards_virtualbox    : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for virtualbox emulation
 - - video_cards_vmware        : VIDEO_CARDS setting to build driver for vmware video cards
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Xorg.0.log will tell you the problem immediately.

My first guess is you're not properly rebuilding x11-drivers/* for 1.13.